# Convert stored procedures from SQL Server 6.5 to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have been using SQL Server 6.5. I am now migrating to SQL Server 2008. How can I restore the stored procedures and data in an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

This would not be easy way since there were some major changes from 6.5 to 7.

One of the ways i suggest to estimate is following:

Upgrade to sql server 2000 first. SQL 2000 has a compatibility option for 6.5 (and 2008 doesnt have it).

After that upgrade to 2008.

Possibly this wont protect you from rewriting your code. Two things i can remember for now are
1) you will have to change all double quotes " to single quote '
2) you will have to check all the NULL checks

I am not sure if the way i suggest will automate all this for you, but chance is this way will save you some time.